# Efficient collision adjustment

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, android-canvas

I've written a augmented reality framework on Android. One feature of the framework is built in collision detection and adjustment; meaning, if a detection is detected the framework will move the objects so they are no longer colliding. It works as expected but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to handle it. Or if there is a general approach in the industry to handle these situations.

The code is called in the onDraw() of an Android View object which is called quite frequently.

Here is the collision detection and adjustment code:

```
private static final Set<Marker> updated = new HashSet<Marker>();
private static final int COLLISION_ADJUSTMENT = 100;

private static void adjustForCollisions(Canvas canvas, List<Marker> collection) {
    updated.clear();

    // Update the AR markers for collisions
    for (Marker marker1 : collection) {
        // If marker1 has already been updated or is not in view then skip it
        if (updated.contains(marker1) || !marker1.isInView())
            continue;

        int collisions = 1;
        for (Marker marker2 : collection) {
            // If marker2 has already been updated or is not in view or is the same as marker 1 then skip it
            if (updated.contains(marker2) || !marker2.isInView() || marker1.equals(marker2))
                continue;

            // Detect a collision
            if (marker1.isMarkerOnMarker(marker2)) {
                // Move the marker "up" the screen by COLLISION_ADJUSTMENT pixels
                marker2.getLocation().get(locationArray);
                float y = locationArray[1];
                float h = collisions * COLLISION_ADJUSTMENT;
                locationArray[1] = y + h;
                marker2.getLocation().set(locationArray);
                marker2.update(canvas, 0, 0);
                collisions++;
                // mark marker2 as updated
                updated.add(marker2);
            }
        }
        // mark marker2 as updated
        updated.add(marker1);
    }
}
```

[Android AR Framework](https://github.com/phishman3579/android-augment-reality-framework) on github.

Comment: This probably fits better on the CodeReview Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Tom G I am not sure I agree. I am not looking for a code review. This seems like it'd be a common problem and I was wonder if there is a general solution/approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to improve is to not use `for(Object o : collection)` this can have a huge impact on performance if you have a lot of objects.

```
for(int i = 0; i < collection.length();i++){

    for(int j = i+1; j < collection.length(); j++){
         //check collision collection[i] vs collection[j]
    }
}
```

The above is better because we only check an object against the ones after it in the collection because previous iterations will have already checked for a collision.

ie on the first iteration, you check the first object (one) against them all so when its time to check object (two) there's no need to check (one) again.

Also in general you want to avoid any work in the `onDraw()` because you want to draw as fast and smooth as possible without getting hung up on caluclations so its better to move them elsewhere.

For further research there are already a few different ideas for optimising collision out there, for example dividing the space into quadrants and only checking objects against other objects in the same quadrants.

edit adding a step through of the loops

```
outer i=0
   inner (check [i] vs [j])
        j=1 [0] vs [1]
        j=2 [0] vs [2]
        j=3 [0] vs [3]
        .....
        j=N [0] vs [N] (N is last index) 
    end inner

we've now checked [0] against all other objects and the inner loop finishes
outer loop incrments i

i++
i=1

outer i=1
   inner (check [i] vs [j])
        j=2 [1] vs [2]
        j=2 [1] vs [3]
        j=3 [1] vs [4]
        .....
        j=N [1] vs [N] (N is last index) 
   end inner
....

i++
i=N-1;

outer i=N-1
    inner (check [i] vs [j])
        j=N [N-1] vs [N]
    end inner
end outer
```

you can see from the step through that [i] never gets checked against itself or any previous indices thus drastically reducing the number of checks needed the further we iterate through the collection.

[0] vs [1] is the same as [1] vs [0] so basically we just eliminate checking the same thing twice.

Comment: Won't (int j = i+1; j < collection.length(); j++) skip objects 0 thru i? I assume it'd still have to check those.

Comment: I'll add an edit with a step through of the loop to better show what it will do.